# GDirections from Google API v2

Tags: android, google-maps-api-2, gdirections

I am trying to use the Gdirections to make my map look a little nicer. Currently I can place all the waypoints on the map, but when I try to create a GDirection object to pass the waypoints into the query I get "GDirections cannot be resolved to a type". I am trying to follow the Constructor on https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/v2/reference#GDirections  but it doesn't seem to work. The line from my code giving errors is as follows:

```
GDirections direc = new GDirections(map);
```

I thought maybe I was not importing the required files, but I don't know what else to add. Currently I am adding

```
import android.graphics.Point;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Display;
import android.view.Menu;

import com.google.android.gms.common.GooglePlayServicesUtil;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdateFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLngBounds;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.MarkerOptions;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.Polyline;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.PolylineOptions;
```

Hopefully I am overlooking something simple. Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[GDirections](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/v2/reference#GDirections) is part of the [Google Maps JavaScript API V2](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/v2/). It is not available in native Android apps (using the Maps v2 API for Android).

[The Google Directions API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/directions/) is a REST based API that you can use in Android for displaying directions.

You can use the [Google HTTP Client Library for Java](http://code.google.com/p/google-http-java-client/) to access the Directions API on an Android device.